# Show all parameter values

Tags: crystal-reports

My parameter field allows multiple values. How can I show all of these values at the top of the report? Currently it only shows one value at a time.

Comment: show us your sql command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parameter is dynamic and takes the form of an array, you'll need to join the values together via a Formula:

```
Join ({?Parameter},", ")
```

Comment: This did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the  **[Can Grow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/976a887c-6423-4627-90dd-887dae75d729/how-to-prevent-the-can-grow-to-overlap-other-element-on-a-report?forum=vscrystalreports)** property for that field. Put this field in a new section so it can easily grow based on your content.

Comment: The join suggestion and the Can Grow together solved the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Ajay,  This was my first posted question and I'm looking on the screen for some way to "Accept" and close the question.  How do I do that?

Comment: welcome dear. just below the upvote/downvote (also please upvote for the right or suitable answers) there is right sign to accept answer  see this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers